How to make Saved Search Result as a default view for all the users when the page is loaded
Our client requires that the Saved Search be set as the default view on the main Asset Listing Page whenever the page is loaded. I know we can make it the default for a specific set of users, but is there a way to make it the standard view for all users?

Yes, you can do this easily. Once you have saved your search, go to your saved search, click on the three dots, and make it public.

Once it is public, click on the three dots again and select 'Edit.' This will open a popup where you can check the 'System Default' box. This will make the saved search the default for everyone.


This works fine on the Search Page of any Entity but wouldn't work for Nested Search.  For instance I want to have a similar Saved Search view on the  Assets Tab on the Product Detail Page

In order to set different saved searches for different types of pages on Content Hub, you can create a user sign-in script which will enable the saved search for the user and then set it as a default saved search.
try {
  bool updateUser = false;
  var user = Context.User;
  await user.LoadMembersAsync(null, new RelationLoadOption("EnabledSavedSearchToUser", "DefaultSavedSearchToUser")).ConfigureAwait(false);

  // Id to be set to as saved search
  var savedSearchId = 12771045;

  var enabledSavedSearchRelation = user.GetRelation("EnabledSavedSearchToUser");
  var enabledSavedSearchRelationIds = enabledSavedSearchRelation.GetIds();
  if(!enabledSavedSearchRelationIds.Contains(savedSearchId)){
    updateUser = true;
    enabledSavedSearchRelationIds.Add(savedSearchId);
    enabledSavedSearchRelation.SetIds(enabledSavedSearchRelationIds);
  }

  var defaultSavedSearchRelation = user.GetRelation("DefaultSavedSearchToUser");
  var defaultSavedSearchRelationIds = defaultSavedSearchRelation.GetIds();
  if(!defaultSavedSearchRelationIds.Contains(savedSearchId)){
    updateUser = true;
    defaultSavedSearchRelationIds.Add(savedSearchId);
    defaultSavedSearchRelation.SetIds(enabledSavedSearchRelationIds);
  }

  if(updateUser){
    // update the user
    await MClient.Entities.SaveAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    MClient.Logger.Error(string.Format("Error in updating Default Saved Search for User {0}", e));
}


Above snippets reads the EnabledSavedSearchToUser and DefaultSavedSearchToUser relations and then enable the saved search for the user and then also set it as a default search when the user signs in the Content Hub.
Note: You will need to make the saved search as public so that it can appear for other users.
You can find more details on the user sign-in script on the below link.
https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/33/cloud-dev/scripting-api--user-sign-in-example.html
Hope this helps!!!
